# Issue when submitting form data via JQuery UI Dialog to the server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have an asp.net mvc app, using JQuery UI dialog. I'm trying to submit form data to the controler action method. I do hit the action method but my object has no data. Do you know why?

**From Filter.cshtml**

```
$("#selectUnits").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Select Units',
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        minHeight: 200,
        buttons: {

            "Cancel": function () {

                $(this).dialog("close");
            },

            "Submit": function () {

                $.post('/Data/SetUnitNumbers', $("#frmSelectedUnits").submit(), function (data) {

                    alert('This worked');
                });

            }

        }  // END OF BUTTONS

    });  //END OF DIALOG
```

**From Controler...Action Method:**

```
 public void SetUnitNumbers(object data)
    {
        int a = 5;            
    }
```

**From SelectUnits.cshtml where form 'frmSelectedUnits' lives. Essentially it is a bunch of checkboxes values that I'm trying to send back to the server:**

```
<body>

<form id="frmSelectedUnits" action="/" >

    <div id="unitNumberCheckboxes" style=" ">
        <div>
             @Html.CheckBox("SelectAllUnitNumbers", false)<label for="SelectAllUnitNumbers"><b>Select/Unselect All Units</b></label>
        </div>
        <div id="unitCheckboxes">


             @foreach (var item in Model)
                {                                            
                    <div style="float:left">

                            @Html.CheckBox("UnitNumbers", false)<label for="UnitNumbers">@item.unit_number.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0')&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>

                    </div>
                }                                
        </div>

    </div>

</form>


</body>
```

Comment: what is your ViewModel you are passing to your view ?

Comment: That is used to create all the checkboxes.  Essentially a list of int values to show the unit numbers next the checkboxes.  Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery `.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is:

```
$.post(url, data, success-callback-function);
```

where **data** is `A map or string that is sent to the server with the request.`

Calling `$("#frmSelectedUnits").submit()` probably won't work.

Try:

```
$.post('/Data/SetUnitNumbers', $("#frmSelectedUnits").serialize(), function (data) {
    alert('This worked');
});
```

[jQuery docs on .serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: I just tried that and it does not appear to be working.  As a test I changed it to $.post('/Data/SetUnitNumbers', "TESTING", function (data).  Note that I put "TESTING" for data.  That too does not send anything to the action method. Not sure what is going on.  To be clear, the action method does get hit with my breakpoint but the value coming in is null.

Comment: @KeelRisk Your `SetUnitNumbers(object data)` is expecting an object? And, you're sending it a `string`? Try changing it to `(string data)`

Comment: @KeelRisk What are you seeing in the console? Chrome and Firefox both have js consoles so you can see what is being sent.

Comment: jk...good question.  So I checked it out and it showed I was sending 'TESTING:' in the body in the request to the server. So essentially TESTING with no value. So then I changed it to:  $.post('/Data/SetUnitNumbers', { TESTING : $("#frmSelectedUnits").serialize(), function...   This is now sending the data to the servier.  For clarification, on my action method I changed the input parameter to string TESTING, so it would match. It works!